# Spawn a new terminal window (Mac OS X)?

Tags: macos, environment-variables, terminal.app

I am often working in a process in the Terminal and I've set some variables and used `cd` and so forth. Then I'd like to open another Terminal window from there. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this little script to do what you want:

```
#!/bin/sh 
osascript <<END 
tell app "Terminal" to do script "cd \"`pwd`\"" 
END
```

place it in one of the folders in your path, make it executable (`chmod +x filename`) and run rehash. You can then run the name of this script to open a new terminal window in the same directory.

[Src](http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?s=&threadid=11554)

Comment: I'm using this, but how would I get it to work without having to run the script. I would like new terminal windows to inherit the last place I cd'ed to. Any easy ideas, or should I open a new question?

Answer (score 7):

What you could do is the following.

Get the current environment in your clipboard:

```
env | pbcopy
```

Open up a new Terminal window and export those environment variables

```
for env in `pbpaste`; do export $env; done
```

And to ease the process, you could always alias it, like so

```
alias get_env="env | pbcopy"
alias set_env="for env in `pbpaste`; do export $env; done"
```

So that all you have to do is

> get_env <kbd>Command+N</kbd> set_env

Comment: Nice +1. I guess this could be remixed with John T's answer to get one single script.

Comment: @dex, thanks for this. I've mashed it together with John T's solution, but I'm getting some errors in the pbpaste part (though it works). `syntax error near unexpected token `do'`

Comment: @yar it might have to do with the fact that I made a typo ("or" instead of "for") in the second alias line. Sorry about that.

Comment: the problem is that the $env cannot be blank and also some other ones do not work, like, TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal. I guess they all need to have a `$`.

Comment: Actually, this only seems to work. the pwd doesn't actually change the directory, it just confused the pwd!

Comment: That's what I found too.
The solution would be to add `cd \`pwd\`` at the end of the script.
If that doesn't work, use `sed` or `awk` to get the value of the PWD line.

Answer (score 6):

```
open -a Terminal .
```

should do the trick.
It simply opens the current directory `.` with the application Terminal.
Of course, you can use any relative or absolute path instead of `.` such as :

```
open -a Terminal ..           # Parent directory
open -a Terminal ~/Documents  # User's documents
open -a Terminal /Library     # System library
```

Comment: awesome and necessary addition to this question. AT the time, I had bigger goals, but now this is more than sufficient.

Comment: So in my `.zshrc` I have `alias shell_here='open -a terminal .'` Fun!

Comment: This is the best answer imo. No scripts necessary, makes a simple process  work simply

Answer (score 1):

You could go to preferences -> general tab and look at the setting 'open new tab with', you can set terminal up to open a new tab in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

To open a new Terminal window you can do open -n /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app 
or also /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal & 
Though I don't know if they will accept an argument such as `cd ~/Documents/` 
Both these make completely new instances though, so to go between them on the keyboard you have to do cmd+tab and not cmd+` 
And if you are going to cmd+tab it always put's the new instance at the end of the queue, so you may have to do shift+cmd+tab