# Mac OS X - How to make a new terminal tab open in current tab's location?

Tags: macos, tabs, terminal.app

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spawn a new terminal window (Mac OS X)?](https://superuser.com/questions/127117/spawn-a-new-terminal-window-mac-os-x)

Hi -

I'm working with the terminal a lot on Mac OS X, and many times use multiple tabs. Each time I open a new tab with Cmd+T, the new tab starts in my ~ folder. How can I get it to open in the same location as the tab I'm currently working on? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this script](http://www.entropy.ch/blog/Mac+OS+X/2008/06/27/Terminal-Tricks-%E2%80%9Cterm%E2%80%9D-revisited-with-tabs.html), it may not work with Cmd+T but it looks like it's as simple as executing the script to open the new tab.