# spawning a new terminal in OSX Snow Leopard: why isn't it working properly?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, osx-snow-leopard

I know I'm supposed to be able to type `open -a Terminal .` to get a new Terminal window running in the current directory. But it doesn't seem to work for me; I get this:

```
Last login: Wed Aug 27 06:52:21 on ttys001
jason-cpu1:~ jason$ /Users/jason ; exit;
-bash: /Users/jason: is a directory
logout
```

It looks like the Terminal program wants to run a command and then exit. How can I tell it not to do this?

---

On the other hand, if I use an explicit path to the Terminal app, it works fine:

```
open -n /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
```

Why the difference in behavior?

Comment: Take a look: http://superuser.com/questions/127117/spawn-a-new-terminal-window-mac-os-x

Comment: No, I've already been there. It's the same topic but the standard answer isn't working for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried the solution with the script? It is not a standard answer ...

Comment: That's not my question. The technique `open -a Terminal .` is supposed to work. I want to know why it's not working in my case, and how to fix it.

Comment: Neither `open -n /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app /tmp` or `open -a Terminal /tmp` opened a new terminal with the current directory set to /tmp for me. 

On the other hand, both `open -a Terminal` and `open -n /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app` opened a new Terminal with the current directory set to the current directory.